# Creating a table that is formatted and in which text is wrapped up

Tags: format, export

I have a big data frame that I would like to convert to a table and later to a png file so I can insert it in my report. However, some of the columns are very wide now.

I am looking for a way to convert this data frame to a table, but in such a way that I can wrap the text in some columns so the table is not as wide as it is now. Thank you very much in advance.